# Gazebo ROS Fuerte PR2 Reset

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I mainly use PR2 in ROS Fuerte with Gazebo. However, whenever something goes wrong, I don't seem to have a reliable way of resetting world/robot. (I haven't tested in Groovy or standalone version.)

Whenever I reset Gazebo by "reset model poses" or "reset world", robot will start sliding in one direction.

Everything is fine when I relaunch Gazebo but that is lots of overhead especially on slower machines.

Is there some other way of reliably resetting to the original state?
Or, it it a known issue?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1550/gazebo-ros-fuerte-pr2-reset/) by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a known issue, tracked here https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/507/issues-with-reset-buttons

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2